# What is the meaning of "fall out of favor"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Biography English movie *Marie Antoinette (2006)*, Scene where Ambassador Mercy warns Marie about 
ignoring Du Barry, King's pleasure giving wife.
Marie Antoinette married Louis XVI, King's grandson.

> Mercy: Du Barry has been complaining to the king that you will not
>   address her. And you cannot afford to **fall out of favor** with the king.
>   Especially as your marriage not exactly on solid ground.
>
> Marie: Fine. I'll talk to her.

Comment: "To fall out of favour" with someone means that you cease being liked by them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fall out of favor:

> To lose someone's approval or acceptance
>
> *idioms.thefreedictionary.com*

In this context it means not being liked or favored by the king any more, which is a very bad situation for a person in the royal court, of course.